# Как определить направление камеры (Android)?

Tags: android

Как определить направление камеры?
Компас - не подходит, т.к. он работает в горизонтальном положении, акселерометр - не дает направление

Comment: Логически посудить. Если устройство неподвижно, то, мне кажется, никак. Не один из компонент внутри устройства, кроме компаса, не может определить направление. В движении gps\глонасс'ом можно вычислить.

Comment: Я тоже к этому пришел, вот ищу варианты

Comment: Что значит направление?
Оси X Y Z найти хотите?

Comment: Любую информацию, которая позволит определить куда направлен телефон. Это может быть вектор, градусы...

Comment: @Николай Нашел, что гуглить нужно по запросу Sensor Fusion Android

Comment: @Igor, получается на уровне ОС происходит комплексный анализ датчиков и уже по этим данным можно что-то вычислить? Опять же, будет телефон нестись под углом продолжительное время(компас не правильно отработает), gps не ловит/отключен и всё, "слияние датчиков" уже не будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать Sensor-Fusion-Tutorial
Пример:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729759/Android-Sensor-Fusion-Tutorial
Или погуглить:
Android Sensor Fusion